# How to publish a Go package

Tags: go

I am trying to publish [my Go package](https://github.com/dylhunn/dragontooth-movegen) so it is visible on [doc search](https://godoc.org/) and [go search](http://go-search.org/), and can be installed with `go get`.

However, the [one document](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackagePublishing) I found doesn't clearly tell me how to get the documentation generated and hosted, or to publish the package at all. How can I publish my package?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You already did it.

All you must do to "publish" a Go package is make it available via a public URL. By putting it on GitHub, you have already published your package. You can view the [GoDoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/dylhunn/dragontooth-movegen) as proof.  It may take time for the doc search to update, but once you've loaded the GoDoc once on your own, the indexing will happen automatically.

As for Go search, just click the [Add Packages](http://go-search.org/add) link at the top of the page.

Comment: @tonix I don't understand your question, but it doesn't really seem related to this answer. If you still are confused, maybe a separate question would be a good idea.

Answer (score 21):

For publishing go modules to public URL and make it visible and downloadable at https://pkg.go.dev/:

First, upload your package to a public URL which must have a [license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639059/how-to-add-license-to-an-existing-github-project) for your package in your case it is

```
github.com/dylhunn/dragontoothmg
```

After this assign a tag to your package source and push it to GitHub for details see https://golang.org/doc/modules/publishing

```
git tag v0.1.0
git push origin v0.1.0
```

Your package will not be searchable immediately until you explicitly tell the [golang proxy server](http://proxy.golang.org) for updating their index using the below command

```
GOPROXY=proxy.golang.org go list -m github.com/<github_user_name>/<module_name>@v0.1.0
```

In your case, it will be

```
GOPROXY=proxy.golang.org go list -m github.com/dylhunn/dragontoothmg@v0.1.0
```